# How to find difference between dates in SQL without creating duplicates?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time-series

I'm trying to create a column that shows the difference between the date of the first vaccination and the date of the second vaccination without creating duplicates.

This is my output before trying the calculation, note only 2 rows are returned.

[image]

When I use the lag function it's turning the 2 rows into 4 rather than just the original 2 rows with the extra column. Is it possible to only return the two rows with the 0 & 86 days difference between vaccination dates?

Here is my code. (I've removed the tables and where clause for privacy reasons)

```
select 

distinct(fie.event_id),
dvd.sql_date vaccination_date,
dvd.sql_date - lag(dvd.sql_date) over (order by dvd.sql_date)diff_between_doses

from (Removed for privacy reasons)

order by
dvd.sql_date
```

This is my output

[image]

Trying to understand why there are two extra rows and how I can get rid of them.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for tables that are representative of your data; `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a **COMPLETE** query (`(Removed for privacy reasons)` is not useful as we cannot see what `JOIN` conditions you are using and that is likely going to be the main focus of an answer); and the expected output for that sample data. Do not post images of data; use text that we can copy/paste and execute.

Comment: Analytic functions do **NOT** generate extra rows so the premise that using `LAG` is turning 2 rows into 4 is flawed; what is likely turning 2 rows into 4 is the `JOIN` condition in the `FROM` clause and that is exactly what you have omitted from the answer and we need to see to be able to answer the question. (Also `DISTINCT` is not a function; it is a keyword and applies to all columns in the result set.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use join in place of Lag. You can the following code:

```
SELECT A.event_id, B.VACCINATION_Date -a.VACCINATION_Date 
FROM vaccine A, vaccine B
WHERE A.VACCINATION_Date=B.VACCINATION_Date
AND (B.VACCINATION_Date -a.VACCINATION_Date) >0;
```